# Difference between "IfWinActive" and "If WinActive()"

Tags: autohotkey

Can anybody explain the difference between `IfWinActive` and `If WinActive()`? I'm really wondering, but Google and official AutoHotkey docs says nothing about.

Comment: Please read this very section: https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s5 . `if winactive` (without `()`,  thus two commands in a row), is no allowed syntax.

Comment: Related: [*Official documentation for IfWinActive / IfWinNotActive / WinActive*](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActive.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `IfWinActive` evaluates to True, the next line of code (or brace-bracketed code block) is performed, or if False, it is skipped.  All it does is evaluate to True or False.

The function `WinActive()` returns the Unique ID (HWND) of the active window if it matches the specified criteria. If it does not, the function returns 0. Since all non-zero numbers are seen as "true", the statement `If WinActive("WinTitle")` is true whenever "WinTitle" is active, and then acts just like `IfWinActive WinTitle`.  Note the quotes in the function, but not the directive.